# How to get rid of thin border of SVG feMorphology/feColorMatrix effect

Tags: svg, inkscape, svg-filters

I would like te create white outline around my drawing but when viewing the result in Firefox or Chrome I see a very thin border around the outline.

[image]

Also in Inkscape I see the outline as black.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
  xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
  xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
  xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
  width="210mm"
  height="297mm"
  viewBox="0 0 210 297"
  version="1.1"
  id="svg8">
  <defs
    id="defs2">
    <filter
      style="color-interpolation-filters:sRGB"
      id="filter42"
      inkscape:label="filter0">
      <feMorphology
        id="feMorphology44"
        operator="dilate"
        radius="2"
        in="SourceAlpha" />
      <feColorMatrix
        id="feColorMatrix46"
        values="1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 "
        result="result1" />
      <feMerge
        id="feMerge48">
        <feMergeNode
          inkscape:collect="always"
          id="feMergeNode52"
          in="result1" />
        <feMergeNode
          inkscape:collect="always"
          id="feMergeNode4537"
          in="SourceGraphic" />
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <metadata
    id="metadata5">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
        rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
          rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
    inkscape:label="Layer 1"
    inkscape:groupmode="layer"
    id="layer1">
    <g
      id="g4541"
      transform="translate(20.312484,-40.090429)"
      style="filter:url(#filter42)">
      <ellipse
        ry="46.113098"
        rx="48.85342"
        cy="177.74852"
        cx="72.854912"
        id="path26"
        style="fill:#ff0000;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.26458332" />
      <rect
        transform="rotate(49.327242)"
        ry="0"
        y="37.731022"
        x="203.59937"
        height="40.205711"
        width="62.978706"
        id="rect28"
        style="fill:#ff0000;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.26458332" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've rewriten your filter. For `feFlood` I'm using `flood-color="gold"`for you to see the "border". You can replace it with `white` or any other color. My only concern is that I don't how it will respond in inkscape. I hope it helps.

```html
<svg
  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
  xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
  xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
  xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
  width="210mm"
  height="297mm"
  viewBox="0 0 210 297"
  version="1.1"
  id="svg8">
  <defs
    id="defs2">
    <filter
      style="color-interpolation-filters:sRGB"
      id="filter42"
      inkscape:label="filter0">

      <feMorphology 
                    id="feMorphology44" 
                    in="SourceAlpha" 
                    result="expanded"
                    operator="dilate" 
                    radius="2"/>
      <feFlood flood-color="gold" result="result1" />
      <feComposite in ="result1" in2="expanded" operator="in" />
     <feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <metadata
    id="metadata5">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
        rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
          rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
    inkscape:label="Layer 1"
    inkscape:groupmode="layer"
    id="layer1">
    <g
      id="g4541"
      transform="translate(20.312484,-40.090429)"
      style="filter:url(#filter42)">
      <ellipse
        ry="46.113098"
        rx="48.85342"
        cy="177.74852"
        cx="72.854912"
        id="path26"
        style="fill:#ff0000;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.26458332" />
      <rect
        transform="rotate(49.327242)"
        ry="0"
        y="37.731022"
        x="203.59937"
        height="40.205711"
        width="62.978706"
        id="rect28"
        style="fill:#ff0000;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.26458332" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, it even looks the same in Inkscape. Just out of curiosity do you know what could be causing that thin border in my example?

Comment: Apparently there is a bug related to the alpha channel for feColorMatrix. Besides it's much easier to set the color using `feFlood`. You can get a explanation for the filter I've used in [Using SVG with CSS3 and HTML5: Vector Graphics for Web Design](https://www.amazon.com/Using-SVG-CSS3-HTML5-Graphics/dp/1491921978/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1542198971&sr=8-1&keywords=amelia+bellamy-royds&dpID=51TL4eoVm%252BL&preST=_SY291_BO1,204,203,200_QL40_&dpSrc=srch)